# how to save rename file zend by override getValues()

Tags: zend-framework

I want to save renamed file name in database . 
I have renamed file with zend rename file filter. 
I am getting new file name but I want to assign that new file name as setValue.
My code in one of my action helper is as follows :

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$fileInfo =   $upload->getFileInfo();

foreach ($fileInfo as $key=>$val) {

  if($form->getElement($key)) {
    $path = $form->getElement($key)->getAttrib('path');
    $getFilePath = Application_Model_File::getFilePath($path);
    $filename = $upload->getFilename();

    $filterRename = new Zend_Filter_File_Rename(array('target' => $getFilePath.$val['name'], 'overwrite' => false,'fileName'=>$val['name'],'prefix'=>$key,'path'=>$getFilePath));
    $upload->setDestination($getFilePath);
    $upload->addFilter($filterRename);


    try {
    $upload->receive($key);
    $FinalUploadedArray = $upload->getFileInfo();
    $newFileName = $FinalUploadedArray[$key]['name']; 

    $form->getElement($key)->setValue($newFileName);
       } catch (Zend_File_Transfer_Exception $e) {
                echo $e->message();
    }
  }
}
```

I want to assign new file name as a setValue of that form file element. 
So once I do `$formData = $form->getValues();` in my controller part I get new file name as a value of respective form file element. 
I have been stuck here for last 2 days.

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Thanks Iti tyagi for Editing my question in proper way. Can anyone have any ideas how to set value of new file name so I can get that in getValues().

Comment: why do you need to assign it back to form ? cant you take that value and store it in db with a model query ?

Comment: Hi Dragon,thanks for the reply. I don't want to do any model or query stuff in my custom action helper. when I do getValues in my controller part I get the original file name so I want to replace it with my renamed file name and for that purpose I was trying setValue but its not working that way I suppose.

Comment: so this code is your custom helper right ? so how are you calling your form, in controller? , does the form still shows the older value ?

Answer (score 0):

well you store the new value directly in database as i suggested in comment,

as for your solution it seems bit odd, if nothing works for you then you can use `zend session` to pass your new value to your controller.

//set value in session

```
        $session = new Zend_session_Namespace('session');
        $session->newval = $newVal;
```

// get value from session

```
        $session = new Zend_session_Namespace('session');
        $newVal = $session->newval ;
```

find out more about zend session [HERE](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.html)

Comment: hello dragon, thanks for your time. I just came to know that zend file form element does not support setValue property. To make this work as per my requirements I have to override the setValue method of Zend_Form_Element_File class in my custom library. After that I can use setValue property for any Zend file form element. Thanks.